# How to iterate over TreeMap in Clojure?

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure

I use Clojure 1.1.0 and I want to iterate over all elements of `TreeMap`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by using `seq`/`doseq` just like with normal clojure maps

```
(doseq [entry treeMap] (
    prn (key entry) (val entry))
)
```

where `treeMap` is your `TreeMap` instance.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, you can also use the `map` function and list comprehensions via the `for` macro to process every entry in a `java.util.TreeMap`:

```
> (def t (new java.util.TreeMap {:a 1 :b 2}))

;; reverse all the pairs
> (map (fn [e] [(val e) (key e)]) t)
([1 :a] [2 :b])

;; same thing, but with destructuring/for
> (for [[k v] t] 
       [v k])
([1 :a] [2 :b])
```